# Calibration about micro photogrammetry

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, photogrammetry

this is my first question in this forum.
I'm working about a project for my thesis. I have to calibrate my camera to import intrinsic parameters in photoscan fo reconstructon 3D of the object which measures maximum 0,7 x 0,7 mm.
I calibrate the camera with openCv, photographing a symmetric pattern glass (0,5x0,5 mm) with circle grid. I do 24 photos, 8 for each kind of inclination ( horizontal vertical and oblique)

1)I would know how can I evaluate the calibration? I read that Reprojection Errors isn't an absolute evaluation, can I compare cx and cy with the real center of the image? Can I evaluate the values of distorsion parameters?(How?)

2) How can improve my method? Do you think that i need of this little ( and perfect) pattern or can I calibrate with chessboard?

Any other suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of results is one of the hardest task in photogrammetry.  Therefore questions are: How accurate do you need to be? Are we talking about about accuracies of 1ppm or 1:1,000? How reliable is your hardware for your goal?

1) The reprojection errors do not really yield anything reliable. It just tells you how the chosen function fits into the measurements (is also often referred as internal accuracy). So if your measurements are garbage the result protocol will happily tell you how well it could fit into your garbage. A reliable evaluation is **only** possible if you have enough external references to get a good approximation for the external accuracy. This can be achieved with precise known distances between targets which have been **not** included in the calibration step to scale the systems. For a solid calibration with a plane calibration body you'll need six of them. Two as a cross on the main diagonal and four on each side.

2) How big are the circles in the image? You might need to correct your image measurements for circle eccentricity before starting your calibration. Is your measurement volume two dimensional? Only in that case a two dimensional calibration field is a good choice. Circle targets are (at the moment) with a huge distance the most reliable,robust and precise targets. Chessboard targets are mostly used in robotics or computer vision but not really when you expect some level of precision. Also the cx, cy approach is a bad choice if you want to achieve some level of precision since it's arbitrary and has no physical basis. Look for a physical equation like the Brown approach to describe your lens. The parameters are mostly referred as: c (focal length), x0,y0 (principal point) ,r0,A1,A2,A3 (radial symmetric distortion),B1,B2 (radial asymmetric distortion) ,C1,C2 (affine distortion).

Comment: Hi, i thank you very much and i'm sorry for my delay. I use an asymmetric circles grid pattern printed on paper which size is 25x15 mm in which there are 13x4 circles, so the diameter of circles is more or less 1,5mm. I don't know if it is the correct size, do you suggest me to change it? how? I need an high accuracy because i have to use theese values( principal point, focal lenght, radial and tangential distorsion) in Photoscan to do a recostruction 3d of a Micro object and then i have to compare the measurement of reconstructured piece with real measures.